# How to prevent other applications from listening to mouse events in macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift5

I am making a macOS app in Swift and the window of my app is always on top of other apps. This is working fine with all apps even if those apps are in full-screen mode. However, when Keynote runs in full-screen mode and my app is on top of it, all the mouse events meant for my app also go to keynote and it exits fullscreen.

I am not sure what's going on but I need to prevent keynote from exiting full-screen. How can I do that?

The window level of my app is `NSWindow.Level.popUpMenu`. And, I have tried the following but nothing has worked so far:

```
window.orderFrontRegardless()
window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
window.order(.above, relativeTo: 0)
```

Comment: @matt can you help me with this by any chance? 

Comment: This helps by any chance? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/FullScreenApp/FullScreenApp.html

Comment: Is a Keynote window in full screen mode or is Keynote running a presentation? Does the mouse event make your app the frontmost app? Post a [mre] please.

Comment: @Willeke Keynote is running a presentation. I did a screencast for the Apple Code-Level Support: https://youtu.be/LHQMVPHaFIA Maybe this can help understand the problem

Comment: @TarunLalwani I can't do fullscreen mode due to the nature of my app but I did try to make my app's window to take the whole screen by setting the window frame to `NSScreen.main.frame` but no luck.

Comment: Did you try using `CGEventTap` to handle events rather than the `NSWindow`/`NSView` hierarchy? As you can actively filter events in the tap, Keynote should not receive the events, though if I recall correctly, this cannot be done in a sandboxed process...

Comment: @CharlieMonroe thanks but I want something that would work in a sandboxed app :(

Comment: It's possible that Apple could grant you a temporary exception via a Mach lookup/register entitlement, but given how I know Apple, I kind of doubt it, but it may be worth a try to ask them via DTS...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR - The problem here is the application activation.**

---

This doesn't answer your question precisely:

> How to prevent other applications from listening to mouse events in macOS?

It's an answer demonstrating how to achieve what you want without preventing other applications from listening to mouse events in macOS.

---

### Active vs inactive window

Check the following screenshots. The first one contains active Xcode window and the other one inactive Xcode window. Your goal is to keep the other application window active even if you click in your overlay. It's irrelevant if the other application is running presentation (like Keynote, in full screen) or not.

[image: Active Xcode window]
[image]

### Sample project setup

- Create a new project (Xcode - macOS App - Swift & Storyboard)
- Open the `Main.storyboard` and remove window & view controller scenes
- Set `LSUIElement` to `YES` (`Info.plist`)
- Add the HotKey Swift package (https://github.com/soffes/HotKey)
- Copy & paste the `AppDelegate.swift` code (below)
- Run it
- Toggle the red overlay with Cmd + Opt + O

I just tested it with the Keynote 10.0 & macOS Catalina 10.15.4 (19E287) and it works as expected - I can click inside the red overlay without interrupting the running presentation, I can control the presentation with keyboard, ...

#### Important parts

- Use `NSPanel` instead of `NSWindow`
- Use `styleMask` & `.nonactivatingPanel` (can't be used with `NSWindow`)

  - Do not activate -> do not deactivate others
- Set `hidesOnDeactivate` to `false`

  - Do not hide when you launch your app, is activated and then you activate any other app
- Set `becomesKeyOnlyIfNeeded` to `true`

  - Avoid being the key window with mouse clicks
  - Search for the `needsPanelToBecomeKey` if you need keyboard input
- Set `collectionBehavior` to `[.canJoinAllSpaces, .fullScreenAuxiliary]`

  - `.canJoinAllSpaces` = the window appears in all spaces (like menu bar)
  - `.fullScreenAuxiliary` = the window with this collection behavior can be shown on the same space as the fullscreen window

#### AppDelegate.swift

```swift
import Cocoa
import HotKey

final class OverlayView: NSView {
    private var path: NSBezierPath?

    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        print("keyDown - \(event.keyCode)")
    }

    override func keyUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        print("keyUp - \(event.keyCode)")
    }

    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        let point = self.convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil)

        path = NSBezierPath()
        path?.move(to: point)
        needsDisplay = true
    }

    override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        path = nil
        needsDisplay = true
    }

    override func mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {
        let point = self.convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil)
        path?.line(to: point)
        needsDisplay = true
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        guard let ctx = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext else {
            return
        }

        defer {
            ctx.restoreGState()
        }
        ctx.saveGState()

        NSColor.green.set()
        ctx.stroke(bounds, width: 8.0)

        guard let path = path else {
            return
        }

        path.lineWidth = 5.0
        NSColor.green.set()
        path.stroke()
    }

    override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool {
        true
    }

    override var needsPanelToBecomeKey: Bool {
        true
    }
}

final class OverlayWindow: NSPanel {
    convenience init() {
        self.init(
            contentRect: NSScreen.main!.frame,
            styleMask: [.borderless, .fullSizeContentView, .nonactivatingPanel],
            backing: .buffered,
            defer: false
        )

        canHide = false
        hidesOnDeactivate = false
        contentView = OverlayView()
        isFloatingPanel = true
        becomesKeyOnlyIfNeeded = true
        acceptsMouseMovedEvents = true
        isOpaque = false
        hasShadow = false
        titleVisibility = .hidden
        level = .popUpMenu
        backgroundColor = NSColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.001)
        collectionBehavior = [.canJoinAllSpaces, .fullScreenAuxiliary]
    }

    override var canBecomeKey: Bool {
        true
    }
}

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    private var hotKey: HotKey!
    private var overlayWindowController: NSWindowController?

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        hotKey = HotKey(key: .o, modifiers: [.command, .option])
        hotKey.keyDownHandler = toggleOverlay
    }

    private func toggleOverlay() {
        if overlayWindowController != nil {
            overlayWindowController?.close()
            overlayWindowController = nil
        } else {
            overlayWindowController = NSWindowController(window: OverlayWindow())
            overlayWindowController?.showWindow(self)
            overlayWindowController?.window?.makeKey()
        }
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I created a class extending NSPanel as you said. Used this class in my storyboard, i.e, replaced NSWindow to the class I created above. Everything works in my app as it was before but still Keynote exits fullscreen when I draw over it. Note: This is how I show the window https://gist.github.com/rampatra/6698d95babaf944ecccbe37aecd7281c

Comment: And, when I don't show the window this way and follow your way `overlayWindowController?.showWindow(self)` then the panel doesn't even show on top of Keynote.

Comment: Your gist doesn't show much, because you're using Storyboard and I have no clue what's set in it. I can only ask if you did follow all the steps I described. You can find complete project [here](https://github.com/zrzka/keynote-overlay). There's animated GIF in the README showcasing how it works. Same code, I just added drawing support.

Comment: One thing based on your gist - the answer says that the you can't active your app, because this is what _forces Keynote_ to hide the running presentation, but you're still using `window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)` & `NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)`.

Comment: Good news. I just changed `NSWindow` to `NSPanel` on my storyboard and checked `Non-activating panel` on the interface builder and it worked. I didn't have to change anything in code. One minor problem though, the key down events aren't being captured (when keynote in presentation mode).

Comment: You didn't mention key events in the question. What do you mean with it? `keyDown`/`keyUp` & `NSResponder`? Or are you trying to make `NSTextField` working for example?

Comment: I didn't realize this issue when I posted the question. Yes, the view controller overrides keyDown method and performs some functions like changing ink color, shape, etc. when certain keys are pressed. Right now it seems Keynote is hogging the keyDown events and not letting my app receive it.

Comment: Answer updated with `keyDown`/`keyUp` support. Sample project as well. Check [this commit](https://github.com/zrzka/keynote-overlay/commit/6a1170c94cb13bf2803fdc6d9e32e3c3dd1a0756) to see what I've done.

Comment: Just the change in your custom NSPanel class did the job. I didn't have to change NSView class. I was already calling `window.makeKeyAndOrderFront()` and didn't know that I also have to override `canBecomeKey`. Can't thank you enough for all the help 